# Where does the anime take place?

Tags: gungrave

Does anyone know what city or country the anime *Gungrave* takes place in? 
I viewed the wiki and read a couple of forums and could not find an answer.

I know it's mafia-based but the anime shows a town similar to how Roanapur is portrayed in *Black Lagoon* as a lawless Thai city.

Comment: It is not placed on any specific country/city. Remember the anime is based on the PS2 game of the same name.

Comment: There isn't really a need for an anime to be based on real life. There can be instances it can be so, but that shouldn't be anything to base your assumptions that it is true for all.

Comment: @Tyhja I agree wholeheartedly, however, if there is a physical city that the developers used to base their design from or physical people I'd love to know who they were or where they were from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anime *Gungrave* was made off a game from what I can tell, it doesn't have much thought into its original setting or a place.

Based off of how the anime is set up, I'd anticipate 70's or 80's era in some part of Japan or Italy, but there isn't a real answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I really think its in Greece or at least easter Mediterranean. A lot of smuggling to the middle east and reminds me of gangs in the Mediterranean.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).